# What does Feed Forward Policy in terms of Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

While reading Reinforcement Learning, I saw the term, Feed Forward Policy and the article also says that it does not have memory, what does "it does not have memory" also mean?

If possible, I hope that somebody turn the following paragraph more expressive words as easy as plainly understandable.

Reference site: **DR as Meta-Learning** part at https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2019-05-05-domain-randomization/

Comment: What are you reading? I think this answer is not possible to answer without more context

Comment: I updated my question with the reference I referred to.